# Session Timeout redirect URL

Tags: liferay, session-timeout

Once the expire pop up appears, how does Liferay know the login URL.?

ex.. if the expired page is

```
'http://localhost:8080/web/2Fsite/2Fmodule'
```

And F5 is pressed,how does Life ray know that the URL is

'`http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home?_58_redirect=%2Fweb%2Fsite%2Fmodule'...`

is this Struts action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet - processServicePrePrincipalException` method:

```
String currentURL = PortalUtil.getCurrentURL(request);
redirect = HttpUtil.addParameter(redirect, "redirect", currentURL);
```